# Android: ServerSocket.accept() randomly freezes

Tags: android, serversocket

I have a `WebView` that is fed from a background thread via a `ServerSocket` on localhost. This works very well, but sometimes the background thread randomly stops accepting requests ("Web page not available"). After some time, it works again without any changes, that is, without restarting the thread or the socket or calling `accept()` again.

**EDIT 2:** Further investigation showed that `WebView` seems to have a (separate?) timeout value for localhost connections that is so small that sometimes the server thread  doesn't get a chance to handle the request. As a workaround, I can reload the page when `WebClient.onReceivedError` is invoked, which eventually loads the page. Anyone having the same problem?

When I open the debugger, I can see that the server thread is still running properly and is waiting (blocked) in the `ServerSocket.accept()` method (or, more precisely, in `OSNetworkSystem.accept(...)`). However, `accept()` doesn't seem to receive the incoming request.

There is is nothing special in my code:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);

while (!shutdown) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        // Parse request and create response
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        // ... close socket
    }
}
```

I use the same code on Windows/Mac and have never experienced any such problems.

This seems to me like a bug in Android, perhaps related to power management optimizations. Any clues?

**EDIT:** The problem does not occur on Android 2.x, only on Android 3.1 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1).

Comment: What contains the code in your question?  Are you running that serverSocket from inside an Activity?

Comment: @elevine: The serverSocket runs in another thread, started from inside an Activity. It does not run as a service.

Comment: Can you show more of your Activity code?  How is the thread created and where do you start it?

Comment: There's nothing special. Basically, it's just new ServerThread().start(). This code is not directly contained in the Activity, but is indirectly called from Activity.onCreate().

Comment: My best guess is that it is not a bug, but rather a characteristic of the Android environment.  Android is constantly managing the lifecycle of your Activity and the process that is running it: http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png .  Running your ServerSocket in a Service *might* solve the problem, but I can't say that for sure.

Comment: I have rewritten my app, that also hangs quite often, for Service and this problem still occurs. I'm using CM7.1 ;[

Comment: @damienix: I have edited my answer to include a workaround. Maybe you can use the same approach in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a bug in Android.

I have filed a bug report under http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19427

**EDIT:** As a workaround, I added some code to reload the page whenever a connection error occurs. This has worked quite well so far.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    String prevFailingUrl;
    int retryCount;
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        if (errorCode == WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT) {
            if (failingUrl.equals(prevFailingUrl)) {
                retryCount++;
            } else {
                retryCount = 1;
            }
            if (retryCount <= 3) {
                webView.reload();
            }
        }
        prevFailingUrl = failingUrl;
    }
});
```